# osgearth show some info “ObjectWrapperManager::addWrapper()”

Tags: osgearth

Ubuntu run osgearth

```
ObjectWrapperManager::addWrapper(): 'osg::DummyObject' already exists.
ObjectWrapperManager::addWrapper(): 'osgEarth::ClampableNode' already exists.
ObjectWrapperManager::addWrapper(): 'osgEarth::InstallCameraUniform' already exists.
ObjectWrapperManager::addWrapper(): 'osgEarth::DrapeableNode' already exists.
ObjectWrapperManager::addWrapper(): 'osgEarth::Util::DrawInstanced::InstanceGeome
```

Who knows what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the OpenSceneGraph serializers for some objects are being registered more than once. I have no idea why that would be -- never seen this before. Wish I could be of more help.